# Data is not Inserted into Database Table

Tags: php, forms, pdo

When the data is entered and submitted, the form doesn't push the data to the database table. Could not find the error.

My table Structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE `maintenance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time1` time(6) NOT NULL,
  `date1` date NOT NULL,
  `dateofchange` date NOT NULL,
  `sender` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reciver` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vehicleno` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `skm` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `engineoil` double NOT NULL,
  `coolant` double NOT NULL,
  `brakefluid` double NOT NULL,
  `battery` double NOT NULL,
  `tyre` double NOT NULL,
  `airfilter` double NOT NULL,
  `electrical` double NOT NULL,
  `wheel` double NOT NULL,
  `dieselfilter` double NOT NULL,
  `vehiclebody` double NOT NULL,
  `others` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `costothers` double NOT NULL,
  `totalcost` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  { 
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
    $time1 = date('H:i:s');
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d');
    $dateofchange=$_POST['dateofchange'];
    $vehicleno=$_POST['vehicleno'];
    $skm=$_POST['skm'];
    $engineoil=(float)$_POST['engineoil'];
    $coolant=(float)$_POST['coolant'];
    $brakefluid=(float)$_POST['brakefluid'];
    $battery=(float)$_POST['battery'];
    $tyre=(float)$_POST['tyre'];
    $airfilter=(float)$_POST['airfilter'];
    $electrical=(float)$_POST['electrical'];
    $wheel=(float)$_POST['wheel'];
    $dieselfilter=(float)$_POST['dieselfilter'];
    $vehiclebody=(float)$_POST['vehiclebody'];
    $others=$_POST['others'];
    $costothers=(float)$_POST['costothers'];
    $user=$_SESSION['alogin'];
    $reciver= 'Admin';
    $notitype='Data Sent';
    $totalcost=$engineoil+$coolant+$brakefluid+$battery+$tyre+$airfilter+$electrical+$wheel+$dieselfilter+$vehiclebody+$costothers;



    $sql="insert into maintenance (time1,date1,dateofchange,sender,reciver, vehicleno,skm,engineoil,coolant,brakefluid,battery,tyre,airfilter,electrical,wheel,dieselfilter,vehiclebody,others,costothers,totalcost) values (:time1,:date1,:dateofchange,:user,:reciver,:vehicleno,:skm,:engineoil,:coolant,:brakefluid,:battery,:tyre,:airfilter,:electrical,:wheel,:dieselfilter,:vehiclebody,:others,:costothers,:totalcost)";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':time1', $time1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':date1', $date1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':dateofchange', $dateofchange, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':reciver', $reciver, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':vehicleno', $vehicleno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':skm', $skm, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query-> bindParam(':engineoil', $engineoil, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':coolant', $coolant, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':brakefluid', $breakfluid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':battery', $battery, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':tyre', $tyre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':airfilter', $airfilter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':electrical', $electrical, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':wheel', $wheel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':dieselfilter', $dieselfilter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':vehiclebody', $vehiclebody, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':others', $others, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':costothers', $costothers, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':totalcost', $totalcost, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute(); 
    $msg="Data Sent";
}    
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#3e454c">

    <title>Edit Profile</title>

    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Sandstone Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap social button library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-social.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap select -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap file input -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fileinput.min.css">
    <!-- Awesome Bootstrap checkbox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css">
    <!-- Admin Stye -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script type= "text/javascript" src="../vendor/countries.js"></script>
    <style>
    .errorWrap {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    background: #dd3d36;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.succWrap{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    background: #5cb85c;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
        </style>


</head>

<body>

<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * from admin_maintenance;";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $cnt=1; 
?>
    <?php include('includes/header.php');?>
    <div class="ts-main-content">
    <?php include('includes/leftbar.php');?>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">Edit Info</div>
<?php if($error){?><div class="errorWrap"><strong>ERROR</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($error); ?> </div><?php } 
                else if($msg){?><div class="succWrap"><strong>SUCCESS</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($msg); ?> </div><?php }?>

<div class="panel-body">
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->email); ?>">


    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle No<span style="color:red">*</span></label>

    <div class="col-sm-4">

<?php

            try
            {
                 $sql1 = "select vehicleno from vehicle";
                 $projresult = $dbh->query($sql1);                       
                 $projresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {   
                die("Some problem getting data from database !!!" . $e->getMessage());
            }

            echo '<select name="vehicleno"  id="vehicleno" class="form-control" >';

            while ( $row = $projresult->fetch() ) 
            {
               echo '<option value="'.$row['vehicleno'].'">'.$row['vehicleno'].'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>';

        ?>          

    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kilometer of Change<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" name="skm" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date of Change<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="date" name="dateofchange" class="form-control" required>
    </div>


   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Engine Oil<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="engineoil" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
 </div>    


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Coolant<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="coolant" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Brake Fluid<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="brakefluid" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Battery<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="battery" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tyre<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="tyre" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Air Filter<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="airfilter" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Electrical<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="electrical" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Wheel Alignment<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="wheel" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Diesel Filter<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="dieselfilter" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">


    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle Body<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="vehiclebody" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Others<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="others" required></textarea>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">


    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cost of Others<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" step=".01" name="costothers" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>



</form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Loading Scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chartData.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function () {          
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.succWrap').slideUp("slow");
                    }, 3000);
                    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No error is triggered.

Comment: `id` is `NOT NULL` but you aren't setting any value. Did you forget the `AUTO_INCREMENT` ?

Comment: I have made the auto increment.

Comment: delete `error_reporting(0);` for see which error do you have.

Comment: There is no error displayed.

Answer (score -2):

I change any small code try to use for see if work and delete `error_reporting(0);`for see error.
I changed:

- $query name because  used much time
- `else{}` contain all page

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();
  include('includes/config.php');
  if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
      {   
  header('location:index.php');
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 
      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
      $time1 = date('H:i:s');
      $date1 = date('Y-m-d');
      $dateofchange=$_POST['dateofchange'];
      $vehicleno=$_POST['vehicleno'];
      $skm=$_POST['skm'];
      $engineoil=(float)$_POST['engineoil'];
      $coolant=(float)$_POST['coolant'];
      $brakefluid=(float)$_POST['brakefluid'];
      $battery=(float)$_POST['battery'];
      $tyre=(float)$_POST['tyre'];
      $airfilter=(float)$_POST['airfilter'];
      $electrical=(float)$_POST['electrical'];
      $wheel=(float)$_POST['wheel'];
      $dieselfilter=(float)$_POST['dieselfilter'];
      $vehiclebody=(float)$_POST['vehiclebody'];
      $others=$_POST['others'];
      $costothers=(float)$_POST['costothers'];
      $user=$_SESSION['alogin'];
      $reciver= 'Admin';
      $notitype='Data Sent';
      $totalcost=$engineoil+$coolant+$brakefluid+$battery+$tyre+$airfilter+$electrical+$wheel+$dieselfilter+$vehiclebody+$costothers;



      $sql2="insert into maintenance (time1,date1,dateofchange,sender,reciver, vehicleno,skm,engineoil,coolant,brakefluid,battery,tyre,airfilter,electrical,wheel,dieselfilter,vehiclebody,others,costothers,totalcost) values (:time1,:date1,:dateofchange,:user,:reciver,:vehicleno,:skm,:engineoil,:coolant,:brakefluid,:battery,:tyre,:airfilter,:electrical,:wheel,:dieselfilter,:vehiclebody,:others,:costothers,:totalcost)";

      $query2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
      $query2-> bindParam(':time1', $time1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':date1', $date1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':dateofchange', $dateofchange, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':reciver', $reciver, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':vehicleno', $vehicleno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':skm', $skm, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $query2-> bindParam(':engineoil', $engineoil, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':coolant', $coolant, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':brakefluid', $breakfluid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':battery', $battery, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':tyre', $tyre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':airfilter', $airfilter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':electrical', $electrical, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':wheel', $wheel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':dieselfilter', $dieselfilter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':vehiclebody', $vehiclebody, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':others', $others, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':costothers', $costothers, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2-> bindParam(':totalcost', $totalcost, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query2->execute(); 
      $msg="Data Sent";
  }    
  ?>

  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en" class="no-js">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#3e454c">

      <title>Edit Profile</title>

      <!-- Font awesome -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <!-- Sandstone Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap Datatables -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap social button library -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-social.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap select -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap file input -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fileinput.min.css">
      <!-- Awesome Bootstrap checkbox -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css">
      <!-- Admin Stye -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

      <script type= "text/javascript" src="../vendor/countries.js"></script>
      <style>
      .errorWrap {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      background: #dd3d36;
      color:#fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
  .succWrap{
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      background: #5cb85c;
      color:#fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
          </style>


  </head>

  <body>

  <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * from admin_maintenance;";
          $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
          $query->execute();
          $result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
          $cnt=1; 
  ?>
      <?php include('includes/header.php');?>
      <div class="ts-main-content">
      <?php include('includes/leftbar.php');?>
          <div class="content-wrapper">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12">

                                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                                      <div class="panel-heading">Edit Info</div>
  <?php if($error){?><div class="errorWrap"><strong>ERROR</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($error); ?> </div><?php } 
                  else if($msg){?><div class="succWrap"><strong>SUCCESS</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($msg); ?> </div><?php }?>

  <div class="panel-body">
  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->email); ?>">


      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle No<span style="color:red">*</span></label>

      <div class="col-sm-4">

  <?php

              try
              {
                   $sql1 = "select vehicleno from vehicle";
                   $projresult = $dbh->query($sql1);                       
                   $projresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


              }
              catch (PDOException $e)
              {   
                  die("Some problem getting data from database !!!" . $e->getMessage());
              }

              echo '<select name="vehicleno"  id="vehicleno" class="form-control" >';

              while ( $row = $projresult->fetch() ) 
              {
                 echo '<option value="'.$row['vehicleno'].'">'.$row['vehicleno'].'</option>';
              }

              echo '</select>';

          ?>          

      </div>
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kilometer of Change<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" name="skm" class="form-control" required>
      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date of Change<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="date" name="dateofchange" class="form-control" required>
      </div>


     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Engine Oil<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="engineoil" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
   </div>    


  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Coolant<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="coolant" class="form-control" required>
      </div>

      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Brake Fluid<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="brakefluid" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Battery<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="battery" class="form-control" required>
      </div>

      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tyre<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="tyre" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Air Filter<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="airfilter" class="form-control" required>
      </div>

      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Electrical<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="electrical" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Wheel Alignment<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="wheel" class="form-control" required>
      </div>

      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Diesel Filter<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="dieselfilter" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">


      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vehicle Body<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="vehiclebody" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Others<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="others" required></textarea>
      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">


      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cost of Others<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="number" step=".01" name="costothers" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
  </div>



  </form>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Loading Scripts -->
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/fileinput.js"></script>
      <script src="js/chartData.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
                   $(document).ready(function () {          
                      setTimeout(function() {
                          $('.succWrap').slideUp("slow");
                      }, 3000);
                      });
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: This should be a comment instead.

Comment: How can i post all code with a 'comment' ? i change part of that code

Comment: Which part? Just `error_reporting(0);`?

Comment: No for example change name of `$query` because he used much time same name, or change `else{` contain all page.

Comment: Why haven't you explained it in your answer? Code-only answers are not very useful and often get deleted.

Comment: i edited my answer sorry for mistake

Comment: This still doesnot solve the problem